# Graphing scatter plot with ordinal, size and histogram dimensions in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I am trying to visualize data in a scatter plot that is time-ordered on the x-axis. I want the size of dots to be dependent on the size of the overall value for a particular time (across columns in the data below). I want the color of the dot to be filled in based on the value for that variable across time (down the rows in the data below), say white for low values and purple for high values.

```
Time      Value_1     Value_2     Value_3      Value_4     Value_5
10:30     100         200         1000         400         300
10:31     200         100         500          200         1000
10:32     300         500         900          300         200
```

In the above, there would be five dots for time 10:30. The third dot would be the largest in size because its value of 1000 is the largest of the total values for 10:30 (total of 2000). Ideally, its size should be half the total area of the remaining dots. The fourth dot would be next largest (with an area of 1/5 the total dots), followed by the fifth dot, second dot and finally the first dot.

The third dot would be colored purple because 1000 is the highest value for Value_3 for each of the times, 10:30-10:32. The third dot at 10:31 would be colored white because it is the lowest of the values for Value_3. The third dot for 10:32 would be very close to deep purple because 900 is much closer to 1000 than it is 500.

Does anyone know how to do this in matplotlib and python? As suggested in the headline question, this is a problem of coloring by histogram position and sizing by value during a specific time. The position of the dot is fixed and ordinal.

Comment: To clarify your question, the sizes for the different rows should have the same scale? Or each row will have each scale, depending on the values encountered? On the first case, for example for all the rows the sizes would go from (0.1 to 1). Or the maximum dot size would be 1 for all rows, with the minimum size of a row dependent on its value ratio to the maximum.

To provide you with an idea, I think you will need to duplicate each of the `value` columns. And then normalize the original  by size and the duplicate column by color, and use that to plot it

Comment: thank you for reading my question. i am not sure what you mean about scales. i ended up solving this by just creating two matricies of the right values and using those as size markers and colors (using a color map). see below.

Answer (score 0):

I split this problem into two matricies and then used these to graph a scatter plot.

```
    #import needed packages
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    
    #reproduce sample chart
    index = ['10:30', '10:31', '10:32']
    df = {'Value_1': [100, 200, 300],
          'Value_2': [200, 100, 500],
          'Value_3': [1000, 500, 900],
          'Value_4': [400, 200, 300],
          'Value_5': [300, 1000, 200]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df, index=pd.to_datetime(index))
    
    print(df)


>                      Value_1  Value_2  Value_3  Value_4  Value_5
> 2020-12-11 10:30:00      100      200     1000      400      300
> 2020-12-11 10:31:00      200      100      500      200     1000
> 2020-12-11 10:32:00      300      500      900      300      200


    #find relative size within a time period -- for size of circle
    relative_size = df.div(df.sum(axis=1),axis=0)
    
    print(relative_size)

>                       Value_1   Value_2   Value_3   Value_4   Value_5
> 2020-12-11 10:30:00  0.050000  0.100000  0.500000  0.200000  0.150000
> 2020-12-11 10:31:00  0.100000  0.050000  0.250000  0.100000  0.500000
> 2020-12-11 10:32:00  0.136364  0.227273  0.409091  0.136364  0.090909


    #find relative size versus all time (for color intensity)
    relative_color = df - df.min()
    relative_color = relative_color / df.max()

    print(relative_color)

>                       Value_1  Value_2  Value_3  Value_4  Value_5
> 2020-12-11 10:30:00  0.000000      0.2      0.5     0.50      0.1
> 2020-12-11 10:31:00  0.333333      0.0      0.0     0.00      0.8
> 2020-12-11 10:32:00  0.666667      0.8      0.4     0.25      0.0

    #for colors
    cmaps = ['Purples'] * int(len(df.keys()))
    
    #plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
    
    for i, col in enumerate(df.keys()):
      ax.scatter(df.index, [i]*len(df.index), c=relative_color[col]/4+.75, s=relative_size[col]*10**3, alpha=1, cmap=cmaps[i])
    #relative color is made to be a minimum of .75 with variations from 0-1 being scaled by 1/4th
    #I chose 10**3 for the relative size just based on preference

    plt.show()
```

[image]